# How to use 2-dimensional array as template argument?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, multidimensional-array

I want to pass a two dimensional array as argument to a template function, without specifying dimensions and without using a macro. Here's the code to demonstrate what I want. The important bits are `makeHow()` method near the middle, and calling it at the end.

**How can I make the `Matrix::makeHow()` method to work correctly?**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <ostream>

class Matrix {

    int rows = 0;
    int cols = 0;
    std::unique_ptr<double> data{};
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &stream, const Matrix &m);

public:
    // just example: this works but is inconvenient
    template<class ARRAY>
    static Matrix make(int rows, ARRAY *source)
    {
        Matrix m;
        m.cols = sizeof(*source)/ sizeof(**source);
        m.rows = rows;
        m.data.reset(new double[m.rows * m.cols]);
        std::copy(&(source[0][0]), &(source[0][0]) + (m.rows*m.cols), m.data.get());
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ": rows * cols = " << m.rows << " * " << m.cols << std::endl;
        return m;
    }

    // just example: this works but is inconvenient, too
    template<int ROWS, class ARRAY>
    static Matrix make(ARRAY *source)
    {
        Matrix m;
        m.cols = sizeof(*source)/ sizeof(**source);
        m.rows = ROWS;
        m.data.reset(new double[m.rows * m.cols]);
        std::copy(&(source[0][0]), &(source[0][0]) + (m.rows*m.cols), m.data.get());
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ": rows * cols = " << m.rows << " * " << m.cols << std::endl;
        return m;
    }

    // THE IMPORTANT PART: this doesn't work, sizeof(ARRAY) is size of pointer
    template<class ARRAY>
    static Matrix makeHow(ARRAY *source)
    {
        Matrix m;
        m.cols = sizeof(*source)/ sizeof(**source);
        m.rows = sizeof(ARRAY) / sizeof(*source);
        m.data.reset(new double[m.rows * m.cols]);
        std::copy(&(source[0][0]), &(source[0][0]) + (m.rows*m.cols), m.data.get());
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ": rows * cols = " << m.rows << " * " << m.cols << std::endl;
        return m;
    }
};

// Convenience macro, has all the ugly macro problems, but works...
#define make_matrix(array) Matrix::make<sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array)>(array)

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &stream, const Matrix &m)
{
    for(int row = 0; row < m.rows; ++row) {
        for(int col = 0; col < m.cols; ++col) {
            auto index = row * m.cols + col;
            stream << m.data.get()[index] << ' ';
        }
        stream << '\n';
    }
    return stream;
}

int main()
{
    double data[][2] = { {1.1, 1.2},
                         {2.1, 2.2},
                         {3.1, 3.2} };
    constexpr int ROWS = sizeof(data)/sizeof(*data);

    std::cout << "\nUsing explicit syntax 1:\n" << Matrix::make(ROWS, data);
    std::cout << "\nUsing explicit syntax 2:\n" << Matrix::make<ROWS>(data);
    std::cout << "\nUsing #define macro:\n" << make_matrix(data);
    std::cout << "\nUsing broken function:\n" << Matrix::makeHow(data); // HOW TO MAKE THIS WORK?
}
```

And this produces the output

```
Using explicit syntax 1:
static Matrix Matrix::make(int, ARRAY*) [with ARRAY = double [2]]: rows * cols = 3 * 2
1.1 1.2 
2.1 2.2 
3.1 3.2 

Using explicit syntax 2:
static Matrix Matrix::make(ARRAY*) [with int ROWS = 3; ARRAY = double [2]]: rows * cols = 3 * 2
1.1 1.2 
2.1 2.2 
3.1 3.2 

Using #define macro:
static Matrix Matrix::make(ARRAY*) [with int ROWS = 3; ARRAY = double [2]]: rows * cols = 3 * 2
1.1 1.2 
2.1 2.2 
3.1 3.2 

Using broken function:
static Matrix Matrix::makeHow(ARRAY*) [with ARRAY = double [2]]: rows * cols = 1 * 2
1.1 1.2
```

Comment: I would switch to `std::array`. It can be easily used in function templates too.

Comment: @digito_evo I'd say `std::array<std::array<double, 2>, 3> data{...};` is so much uglier than `double data[][2] = ...;`, and doesn't really provide any additional type safety when used in templates like here, that I think I prefer the solutions shown in the answers.

Comment: That's your opinion though. I personally think that it's more expressive (and not uglier). Also, you only declare and write it a few times and the rest is just `data[y][x]` similar to raw arrays.

Comment: @digito_evo Yeah. As an exercise, I wrote `make` method also for a nested `std::array`, the correct syntax for the method is the same really.

Answer (score 1):

To pass an array as a templated item, you need to also template the dimensions:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
void f( T (&xs)[ N ] )
{
  for (auto x : xs)
    ...
}
```

For a two-dimensional array you just need to add another dimension:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t R, std::size_t C>
void f( T (&xs)[ R ][ C ] )
{
  for (auto & row : xs)
    for (auto x : row)
      ...
}
```

Remember, however, that every different array you have will generate a new function in your executable. I prefer to use the templated stuff to generate inline functions to interface with a more primitive low level function that works over a 1D array but knows how to compute the indices into each row and column (because the template passes along the dimensions of the array). That way only the more primitive version creates code, and the inline template functions disappear.

Comment: I'll see if I can get this to work, but for answer completeness maybe provide functions which would work with the question code?

Comment: You can do that yourself. Replace `f` with `makeHow`, replace `T` with `ARRAY`, etc. Then your `m.cols = C;` etc. (The point is for you to understand. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I got it to work, but it's easier to understand for others later, if the code in the answer matches the code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class ARRAY>
static Matrix makeHow(ARRAY & source)
//                          ^
//                          |
//                          |
//               +---------------------+
//               | this one right here |
//               +---------------------+
{
    Matrix m;
    m.rows = sizeof(source)  / sizeof(*source);
    m.cols = sizeof(*source) / sizeof(**source);
    ... etc
}
```

Comment: D'oh! So simple...

Comment: This might be improved by adding `constexpr auto ROWS = std::size(source); constexpr auto COLS = std::size(*source);` to get the dimensions in a nicer way.